# Unable to open video in same window from iframe?

Tags: instagram

I have some code to display video from instagram in my blog.The code is going well.But I am facing small bugs.Video is opening in new window.But I want to play it in same window.I am giving my code below :

```
<iframe id="iframecode" onload="" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="536" src="http://instaembedder.com/gallery.php?hashtag=music&amp;type="video/mp4"&amp;width=150&amp;cols=3&amp;frame=1&amp;image_border=10&amp;rows=4&amp;cell_margin=10&amp;comments=1&amp;date=1&amp;link=1&amp;caption=0&amp;color=gray" style="height: 804px;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

This not possible because the embed HTML links have **target="_blank"** so this will always open up the video in a new browser window. The links in the embedded IFRAME look like this:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://instaembedder.com/post.php?id=643010106628385295_635451161"><div style="background-image: url(http://distilleryimage11.s3.amazonaws.com/29afd3e887bc11e398e11297a3d38eb7_5.jpg)" class="div-img"></div></a>
```

This is no way to overide or change the **_blank** target.